# Python 2.7 - how to get input, but don't show keys entered

Tags: python

I want to make it so that I'm taking input

```
enterKey = raw_input("String here: ")
```

But that any keys entered are not displayed - it should just act as a pause of sorts in the script until Enter/Return is pressed and then it can proceed.

Comment: Why, what's bad about displaying something if the user types it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python read a single character from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: Maybe passwords?

Answer (score 25):

Use [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html).

```
import getpass
keys = getpass.getpass("String here: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

[getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html) : Prompts use to enter keys but it don't displays it.

You can use it as An interactive CLI Python program, which requires entering of password.

```
import getpass
key = getpass.getpass("enter Key :")
```